# How do I decompose the partial fraction for an inverse Laplace Transform?

Tags: partial-fractions, inverse-laplace

I'm working through an example of an inverse Laplace transform, starting with:

$$\hat{F}(s)=\frac{1}{(s^2+1)(s^2+2)}$$

From this, I know to rewrite it using partial fractions, to get $\frac{1}{(s^2+1)(s^2+2)}=\frac{A}{s^2+1}+\frac{B}{s^2+2}$, which I then simplify as:

$$1=A(s^2+2)+B(s^2+1)$$

I know from the example that $A=1$ and $B=-1$, but I cannot for the life of me find the process behind this step. If somebody could help me understand it, I'd be very grateful.

Comment: You know that if two polynomials are equal, this means each coefficient is equal.

Comment: Do you see why that $A$ and $B$ work when you plug them in?

Comment: Your starting point is wrong, it should be $$\frac{1}{(s^2+1)(s^2+2)}=\frac{As+B}{s^2+1}+\frac{Cs+D}{s^2+2}$$ as you have irreducible quadratic factors, not linear ones.

Comment: @Tbw omg I see! I knew it would be something really obvious in hindsight lol. In general to solve inverse LTs where you don't already know A and B, is it just a case of trying solutions to see what works?

Comment: @Paul I don't think this is the case, the example has all three solutions (partial fractions, convolution, and Bromwich integral) and the answers all agree (as you'd hope!) In the workings for the partial fractions method, it only uses A and B.

Comment: It works because A and C are 0, pure good fortune. In general, you need 4 constants for two such quadratic factors.

Comment: @Paul Ah I see, that makes sense. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

$$\newcommand{recp}[1]{\frac{1}{#1}}$$
As [Paul](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/138918/paul) said,we need four unknowns instead of two, but the linear coefficients will be $0$ as we will see shortly
$$\hat{F}(s)=\recp{(s^2+1)(s^2+2)}=\frac{As+B}{s^2+1}+\frac{Cs+D}{s^2+2}$$
Multiplying both sides by the left denominator:
$$1=(As+B)(s^2+2)+(Cs+D)(s^2+1)=As^3+2As+Bs^2+2B+Cs^3+Cs+Ds^2+D$$
Since this is for all $s$, we can separate the coefficients:
$$\begin{cases}
(1)A+C=0\\(2)B+D=0\\(3)2A+C=0\\(4)2B+D=1
\end{cases}$$
Subtracting the equations and plugging in:
$$(4)-(2)=B=1\\
1+D=0\\D=-1\\(3)-(1)=A=0\\C=0$$
Therefore
$$\hat{F}(s)=\recp{s^2+1}-\recp{s^2+2}$$